# Error en login con mi base de datos

Tags: java, mysql

estoy tratando de hacer un login que tome datos en mis 2 txtfield y los valide con mi base de datos.

```
int resultado=0;

    try {

        String usuario=txtusuario.getText();
        String pass=String.valueOf(txtpass.getPassword());

        String sql="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Usuario='" +usuario+ "' and Contraseña='" +pass+ "' ";
        Statement st=(Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

        if(rs.next()){

            resultado=1;

            if(resultado==1){

                MenuPrincipal form=new MenuPrincipal();
                form.setVisible(true);
                this.dispose();
            }else{

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos invalidos");
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos invalidos" + e.getMessage());

} 
    }
```

El programa inicia sin ningún error conectándose a la bd pero al momento de ingresar el usuario y contraseña me sale datos inválidos, es como si ni los buscara en mi tabla de la base de datos.

Esta es mi clase ConexionBD

```
public class ConexionBD {

    static com.mysql.jdbc.Statement createStatements() {
        return null;

    }
    Connection cn;

    public Connection conexion(){

        try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/*****","root","");
        System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");


    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }return cn;
    }

    Statement createStatement(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Error de conexion");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funciono poniéndolo de esta forma

```
     try {

    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Usuario=? and Contraseña=?");

    ps.setString(1, txtusuario.getText());
    ps.setString(2, new String(txtpass.getPassword()));
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

    if (rs.isBeforeFirst()) { 
        MenuPrincipal form=new MenuPrincipal();
        form.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();     
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos invalidos");
    }   
} catch (Exception e) {

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error de consulta" + e.getMessage());

}
```

Comment: Hola!, por favor puedes mencionar que fue lo que cambiaste?

Comment: Quite el `PreparedStatement ps = null;` y puse un `SELECT * FROM` como hice en otra ventana que mostraba los productos de una tabla de la bd.

Comment: Por favor, edita y añade esta explicación a tu respuesta :)

Answer (score 3):

Puedes intentar la consulta de este modo.

Aquí se usa `PreparedStatement` para blindar el código contra ataques de *Inyección SQL*, así como el método `isBeforeFirst()`, más adecuado para saber si un conjunto de resultados está vacío. También, es más óptimo para este caso usar `SELECT COUNT(*)` que un `SELECT *`

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {

    String sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE Usuario=? and Contraseña=?";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, txtusuario.getText());
    ps.setString(2, new String(txtpass.getPassword()));
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery(sql);

    if (rs.isBeforeFirst()) { 
        MenuPrincipal form=new MenuPrincipal();
        form.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();     
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos invalidos");
    }   
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error de consulta" + e.getMessage());
}
//Cerrar recursos si es preciso
```

Así debería funcionar, a no ser que la contraseña haya sido encriptada al momento de guardarla en la base de datos. Si es así debes mostrar el código de inserción para ver cómo estás encriptando el dato.

Quiero llamar la atención también sobre la forma de nombrar tus elementos, evita usar la letra `ñ` o caracteres especiales en el nombre de tablas, columnas, variables, ya que su uso puede traer problemas en ciertos entornos sensibles a la codificación, lo digo por que veo que nombraste a una columna de la base de datos `Contraseña`.

Comment: Me da un error en 'ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);' algo anda mal con mi clase ConexionBD.

Comment: Ahi edite mostrandote la clase ConexionBD que no podia ponerlo aca

Comment: @Benji el `return cn;` debería ir dentro del `try`. Y donde uses la conexión tienes que crear una instancia de la clase y llamar al método `conexion()`, algo así: `Conexion db=new ConexionBD(); Connection con=db.conexion(); //Usar con` Doy por supuesto que verificaste que la conexión funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, logre solucionarlo guiándome por como estaba escrito el código en otra ventana.

Comment: @Benji me alegro de que se haya resuelto. Si alguna de las respuestas dadas ha servido para resolver el problema puedes marcarla como aceptada para que la pregunta no aparezca como no resuelta. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Este metodo?

```
public class Prueba {

public static void main(String[] args) {
         //Codigo
}                                                                                          }
```

Comment: Estas preguntando o afirmando?

Comment: Claro eso es un metodo main si xd lo que pregunto es donde debería ponerlo, por que me sigue saltando el mismo error.

Comment: Segun tengo entendido va siempre va al inicio, es el punto de partida de los programas de java. Tendria que ir el codigo dentro de este metodo sin que haya otro codgo afuera...

Comment: NO es necesario que vaya al inicio, esto no responde a la pregunta.